# How to extract a number from a website using javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing

I want to extract a special number from this website:

[stackoverflow-google-plus-counter](https://plusone.google.com/u/0/_/%2B1/fastbutton?count=true&url=http://www.stackoverflow.com/)

If you look at the html code of this website you see:

*SOME STRTINGs* ..window.__SSR = {**c: 2337.0** ,si:1 ...*SOME STRTINGs*

and I need this number after **c:**

at the moment it is 2337

How to get it?

I need this number as global variable, because I want to do some math with it.

Short working example would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you open the js console in chrome and type `window.__SSR.c` it will return your number.

If you wanted to turn it into a global variable then just put `var myNumber = window.__SSR.c;` at the top of your script.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I dont understand how I can implement it  in the code of my website.
Could you make a small example?